# Destructure array property values from reducer store

Tags: reactjs, redux

**GOAL:** Destructure array property values from reducer store and render them on my webpage

However, when I try to access the array values, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Here is the dispatch to my reducer:

```js
const handleOver = () => {
    if (profile && links) {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_DISCOVER_PROFILE",
        item: {
          firstNameDiscover: profile.firstName,
          lastNameDiscover: profile.lastName,
          usernameDiscover: profile.username,
          imageUrlDiscover: profile.imageUrl,
          linksDiscover: [links],
        },
      });
    }
    console.log("IM HOVERING");
  };
```

This is what my console prints after the dispatch:

[Dispatch values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrA8i.png)

Here is how the values are stored in my reducer:

```js
export const initialState = {
 
  discoverProfile: {},
  
};
```

This is how I am destructuring the values from my store:

```js
function PhoneMockupDiscover() {
  const [
    {
      discoverProfile: {
        firstNameDiscover,
        lastNameDiscover,
        usernameDiscover,
        imageUrlDiscover,
        linksDiscover,
      },
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useStateValue();
```

When I render the following, the values are pulled from the store properly:

```js
<div className="profile__image">
            <img src={imageUrlDiscover} />
          </div>
          <div className="profile__container">
            <h5>
              {firstNameDiscover} {lastNameDiscover}
            </h5>
            <p>@{usernameDiscover}</p>
          </div>
```

However, when I try to map through the array of `linksDiscover` array with:

```js
<div className="linksOnPhone__wrapper">
          {linksDiscover.map((link) => (
            <LinkOnPhone linkTitle={link.linkTitle} linkUrl={link.linkUrl} />
          ))}
        </div>
```

...I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Here is my `StateValue` code:

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

// create the data layer
export const StateContext = createContext();

// Build a provider so we can wrap entire app inside of provider so we access data layer
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

// This is where we use it in a component
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: What is your initial `useStateValue` value? Is this in a reducer? Can you update question to include the `useStateValue` hook code?

Comment: @DrewReese Just updated man

Comment: What is the value of `initialState`?

Comment: @DrewReese Added that too: ```discoverProfile: {},```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`linksDiscover` is initially undefined, so it can't be mapped.

```
export const initialState = {
  discoverProfile: {},
};
```

This means `discoverProfile.linksDiscover` is undefined so trying `discoverProfile.linksDiscover.map(...` throws the error.

## Solution

Provide some more complete initial state

```
export const initialState = {
  discoverProfile: {
    firstNameDiscover: '',
    lastNameDiscover: '',
    usernameDiscover: '',
    imageUrlDiscover: '',
    linksDiscover: [],
  },
};
```

Or provide fallback values in the component for any undefined destructured values

```
function PhoneMockupDiscover() {
  const [
    {
      discoverProfile: {
        firstNameDiscover = '',
        lastNameDiscover = '',
        usernameDiscover = '',
        imageUrlDiscover = '',
        linksDiscover = [],
      },
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useStateValue();
```

This will ensure that `discoverProfile.linksDiscover` is a defined array and able to be mapped.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! One more thing though! When I map through the values in my ```linksDiscover```` with ```{linksDiscover.map((link) => (
            <LinkOnPhone
              linkTitle={link.linkTitle}
              linkUrl={link.linkUrl}
              active={link.active}
            />
          ))}``` I can't pass down the values of the array as props. Any ideas?

Comment: @RogerStaxx It may depend on what `LinkOnPhone` is doing with the passed props. Have a running codesandbox with this code that can be inspected?